# Trying to run TLS1.2 on XP sp3 with .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, windows-xp

Before we begin, I am aware the proper thing would be to upgrade the OS. I am trying to work around this issue and as you might imagine there are a lot of dead ends. I found something that seems to work but I am not clear on why specifically and looking for some help.

Windows XP does not support SSL/TLS 1.1/1.2
[Source 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/)
[Source 2](https://knowledge.symantec.com/kb/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO19176)

.Net 4.0 does not support TLS 1.2
[Source 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.100).aspx)

.Net 4.5+ does support TLS 1.2 but cannot be installed on XP
[Source 4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp/) [Source 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you override ServerCertificateValidationCallback with your own cert
validation it works. Why? What is going on? Is it really working? Its
appears to be communicating over SSL. Network operations assures me
there is no fall back SSL/TLS on the server.

Alternatives: Get self signed cert for older TLS 1.0, cant get this
from CA anymore
use other C++ library or similar that supports TLS 1.2
and call it from .NET

UPDATE 1:
I still dont know why the ServerCertificateValidationCallback seems to work. Now I am looking to see what Cipher Suite is supported by specifically XP SP3. I am looking at packets and using this article as a guide. As was pointed out, even if I find an alternative library if the Cipher Suite is not being served or accepted I am still no go with a solution.

[cipher suite guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299520/how-to-determine-the-cipher-suite-for-the-server-and-client)

I did try SecureBlackBox with some success (was TLS1.2) but I could not get it to authorize the cert from the cert authority.
https://www.eldos.com/sbb/

UPDATE 2: Learning a lot of how this works Thank you Mr Ullrich et. al.

UPDATE 3: At this point I am looking at using an Apache Proxy on the XP machine to do the TLS1.2 SHA256 CA verification communication (Non Windows Stack) and having my .net 4.0 communication to talk to this proxy locally (on machine), while any communication leaving the machine is properly secured.

Comment: Thats so helpful thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate and the validation of the certificate has nothing to do with the TLS version. You can use the same certificate with SSL 3.0 ... TLS 1.3. But just because your certificate can be used with all of these does not make your local TLS stack magically aware of how the TLS 1.2 protocol works.

If you want TLS 1.2 support on Windows XP look outside of the Windows TLS stack, i.e. look at OpenSSL, NSS and other libraries. It looks like that there is a library offering support for recent OpenSSL in .NET, but I'm not sure if this will still work on XP. See https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net.

Comment: So is it communicating SSL/TLS? and if so what version? Is it SHA256? My understanding is that you can purchase a certificate that is SHA256 and TLS 1.2 can handle it and TLS 1.0 cant. What am I missing are these unrelated?    I will look at the link you mentioned, Thanks!

Comment: @JoeVolcano: *" My understanding is that you can purchase a certificate that is SHA256 and TLS 1.2 can handle it and TLS 1.0 cant. "* - this understanding is wrong. Again, the certificate is practically independent of the TLS version. You can use a SHA-256 signed certificate with TLS 1.0 too. Any limitations only depend on the actual implementation but not the protocol.

Comment: So I should be able to use a new cert that is SHA 256 and configure my server to allow TLS  1.0 in addition to TLS 1.2 and I can have normal SSL communication to a .net 4.0 (TLS 1.0)  module running on xp service pack 3?

Comment: @JoeVolcano: If the TLS stack does not support TLS 1.2 (i.e. SChannel on Windows XP) it does not help if you use a certificate which could in theory be used with TLS 1.2.

Comment: @JoeVolcano: in this case it is probably not a problem of TLS 1.0 vs. TLS 1.2 at all but a problem of missing [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), i.e. the server does speak TLS 1.0 (supported by XP) but does require SNI (probably not supported) and serves you the wrong certificate when accessed without SNI.

Comment: I analyzed the handshake packets and observed it seems to be using TLS1.0. I used a non windows stack socket module and still no luck. Mainly I think it is struggling to verify the SHA256 cert with the ca. It is able to communicate using the new cert ssl if I ignore the verification. The server does support SNI but we only have one cert so not sure how we could get the wrong cert since there is only one and it works if we override the validation of the cert.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the current information what's going on but I doubt that it is related to SHA-256 since both XP (latest SP) and OpenSSL should be able to deal with this. If you use the OpenSSL backend it is more likely that it does not find the trusted root since I doubt that OpenSSL uses the Windows trust store.